# PowerShell Use File Dialog OR User Entry for Computer List

Tags: powershell

When I write PowerShell scripts they are typically to be used against many computers.  Since we use a text file with a list of computers, I write my scripts with the following function:

```
Write-host "Select Text/CSV File with List of Computers"

#Provides Dialog Box to select a file with list of computers.  File must contain only 1 of each of the Computer name(s) per line
Function Get-OpenFile($initialDirectory)
{ 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
}

$InputFile = Get-OpenFile
If($InputFile -eq "Cancel"){
Write-host "Canceled By User"
exit}
Else{
$Computers = @(get-content -path $InputFile)
}
```

If I'm writing a script to be used for a single computer, I use the following:

```
$computer = Read-Host "Enter hostname"
```

My question is, how can I write these scripts to do the following:

- A) the Get-OpenFile command to parse the computer names
- B) if the Get-OpenFile is canceled, have the script prompt for a computer name using Read-Host
- C) if the Read-Host entry is empty, then cancel the script

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would combine the two into a single function:

```
function Get-ComputerName
{ 
    param(
        $InitialDirectory = ([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::MyDocuments))
    )

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
    $OpenFileDialog.Filter = 'Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*'

    # Show OpenFileDialog window and test result
    if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK'){
        # A file was picked, read it
        $Computers = Get-Content -Path $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    } else {
        # No file chosen, prompt user
        $Computers = @(Read-Host 'Enter hostname:')
        if($Computers[0] -like '*,*'){
            # Input contains comma, assume multiple names
            $Computers = $Computers[0] -split ','
        }
    }

    # Dispose of file dialog
    if($OpenFileDialog){
        $OpenFileDialog.Dispose()
    }

    # Return computer names
    return $Computers
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't not call the file dialog for file selection.  Other ideas?